# E and F being events, F is independent of E but E is not independent of F. Any example?

Tags: conditional-probability

I was doing independent events and there I found that any two events(say $E$ and $F$) are independent when:
$$P(F|E)=P(F)$$
provided $P(E)\ne0$

and $$P(E|F)=P(E)$$
provided $P(F)\ne0$

I'm having problem in understanding that why we have to work out the above two equations in order to see that $E$ and $F$ are independent.

I think that when $F$ is independent of $E$ then $E$ is also independent of $F$.

**How can this happen that $E$ is independent of $F$ but $F$ is dependent of $E$.**

Kindly provide me an example in which first event is independent of second but second is dependent on first.

Comment: If $P(E) = 0$, what is **your** definition of $P(F\mid E)$? The _commonly_ accepted definition of $P(F \mid E)$ is $$P(F \mid E) = \frac{P(F\cap E)}{P(E)}\quad\text{provided that}~ P(E) > 0$$ and is silent (in elementary treatments such as the one you are likely reading) about what $P(F\mid E)$ means when $P(E) = 0$.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Sorry sir that was a typing mistake. I have just corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible. If $E$ is independent of $F$, then the converse is true as well ($E$ and $F$ *are* independent). To see why, recall that 
$$
\Pr[E\mid F] = \frac{\Pr[E\cap F]}{\Pr F} = \frac{\Pr[E\cap F]}{\Pr E}\frac{\Pr E}{\Pr F} = \Pr[F\mid E]\frac{\Pr E}{\Pr F}
$$
so that $\Pr[E\mid F] = \Pr[E]$ if and only if $\frac{\Pr[F\mid E]}{\Pr F} = 1$, i.e. $\Pr[F\mid E] = \Pr F$. Note that the "usual" (equivalent) definition of independence is $\Pr[E\cap F] = \Pr[E]\cdot\Pr[F]$.

Answer (score 2):

Formally $P\left(F\mid E\right)$ is defined by the condition: $$P\left(F\mid E\right)P\left(E\right)=P\left(E\cap F\right)$$
If $P\left(E\right)\neq0$ this comes to the same as $P\left(F\mid E\right)=\frac{P\left(E\cap F\right)}{P\left(E\right)}$.

However if $P\left(E\right)=0$, then, since $(E\cap F) \subset E$, it follows
that $P(E\cap F) \leq P(E)$ and so $P(E\cap F)$ also equals $0$. Thus, the
definition of $P\left(F\mid E\right)$ as a fraction becomes of the form
$\frac{0}{0}$ and cannot be used to decide the value of $P\left(F\mid E\right)$.
Nor does $P(F \mid E)\cdot P(E) = P(E\cap F)$ help because $P(F \mid E)\cdot 0 = 0$ is true for all choices of value for $P(F \mid E)$.

Two events $E$ and $F$ are **by
definition independent** if: $$P\left(E\cap F\right)=P\left(E\right)P\left(F\right)$$
Note that this is an expression *symmetric* in $E$ and $F$. Note also that
if either $P(E)$ or $P(F)$ equals $0$, then $P(E\cap F)$ also necessarily
equals $0$ and so $P(E\cap F)=P(E)P(F)$ automatically holds: an event
of probability $0$ is independent of all other events.

Statement "$E$ is (in)dependent of $F$" must be read as: "$E$ and $F$ are (in)dependent".

If $P\left(E\right)\neq0$
then it comes to the same as $P\left(F\mid E\right)=P\left(F\right)$
and if $P\left(F\right)\neq0$ then it comes to the same as $P\left(E\mid F\right)=P\left(E\right)$.

I advice you *not* to use these conditional expressions as *definition* of independence.
The special cases $P\left(E\right)=0$ and/or $P\left(F\right)=0$
are somehow spoiling.

Comment: Sir please look at the question once again I just edited it. Sorry.

Comment: Well, what you say to "think" in your question is correct. Examples what you are asking for are not there. If $E$ is independent of $F$ then $F$ is independent of $E$. Or rather: then $E$ and $F$ are independent (symmetric).

Comment: @drhab I edited your answer to incorporate additional commentary. Please roll back to the previous version if you do not like the changes.

Comment: @DilipSarwate It's fine. Thank you.